# Shake Animation not working properly

Tags: android

Here is xml code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="10" android:duration="1000" 
android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7" />
```

Here is cycle_7.xml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cycleInterpolator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      android:cycles="7" />
```

And this is the way i am using it .

```
final Animation animAlpha2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim);
v.startAnimtion(anumAlpha2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: i mean it's not even shaking to the component.

Comment: Try using percentage as in android:toXDelta ="10%". 10px is just too little for you to notice anything.

Comment: I have tried this but still it was not working, am i missing something??

Comment: Maybe replace the `android:interpolator` by `android:repeatCount="7"` and `android:repeatMode="reverse"`.

Comment: Thank you so much now it's working .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `android:interpolator="@anim/cycle_7"` line by:

```
android:repeatCount="7"
android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

That should do the trick. `repeatCount` set the number of cycles the animation will perform and `repeatMode` which can assume [two values](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android:repeatMode), `repeat` and `restart`.